# Creating a pair from temporaries

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I try to construct a pair from temporaries. From what I understand, std::pair provides the necessary constructors, but I cannot make it work. This is my minimal example:

```
#include <utility>

struct Test {
  Test() : a(1.0) {}

private:
  double a;
  Test(Test&&) = default;
  Test(const Test&) = delete;
  Test& operator=(Test&&) = delete;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  std::pair<Test, double> result(Test(), 0.0);
}
```

I tried to compile this with `clang++-3.8 --std=c++14`.
The copy constructor for Test is invoked by pair. Because it was deleted, I get the error `call to deleted constructor of 'Test'`. It does not seem to be a problem with the compiler though, because I get a similar error with gcc, see https://ideone.com/n5GOeR.

Can someone explain to me why the above code fails to compile?

Comment: Since you left no way to copy or move a `Test`, how do you expect `std::pair`'s constructor to do it ?

Comment: I tried to explicitly enable the move constructor for `Test`.

Comment: Once you put the move constructor inside the `public` section, [it works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77a1983a12219dfc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My gcc (6.1.1) gives a slightly different error message, which is more helpful:

```
t.C:8:3: note: declared private here
   Test(Test&&) = default;
   ^~~~
```

Your move constructor is private. It obviously must be public.

Comment: What's odd is that this is the (deleted) copy constructor, which should not be chosen by overload resolution. I don't know which version of GCC Ideone uses, but it looks like it has a bug.

Comment: Yes, my gcc gives a better diagnostic. Updated.

Comment: @Quentin This is strange, i just tried on gcc.godbolt.org and every version of GCC starting with 4.4.7 (the oldest they have) correctly errors about the move constructor being private.

Comment: @Quentin But clang for some reason tries to use the copy constructor and complains about it being deleted. So apparently ideone uses Clang. And interesting question: which one is correct here?

Comment: @IlyaPopov the move constructor should definitely be chosen here : capturing rvalues is the whole point of it.